# Can I use my Chariot (now Thule) child carrier hitch on my Juiced Crosscurrent S?

Tags: electric-bike

I recently bought a used Chariot Cougar 1 child bike trailer / carrier from Craigslist. This same trailer design is now under the brand "Thule." It works great, and the included hitch fits on my Gravity Comp 20, my partner's Gravity Comp 30, and my partner's Santa Cruz mountain bike (converted to an e-bike). However, my Juiced Crosscurrent S rear axle isn't compatible with the hitch. (It also does not fit either of our Jamis Dragonslayer mountain bikes.) I want to do my share of daycare drop-offs but with steep hills in San Francisco, I'm struggling.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot either an adaptor or an alternate hitch design to let me use my Chariot (now Thule) hitch on my Juiced e-bike?

**Juiced Crosscurrent S rear axle:**

[[image: Size of my rear axle size1]

Juiced bike: https://www.juicedbikes.com/products/crosscurrent-s2

**Hitch for bike trailer: Thule Model #     40191109**
[image: Thule rear axle hitch]

https://www.etrailer.com/Accessories-and-Parts/Thule/50103033.html?feed=npn&gclid=CjwKCAiAxp-ABhALEiwAXm6IyUcJJB4yO5G6W6UZIJqQSP5o58DL5ar1cp_1YXNxylANcHVbJIBooBoCySMQAvD_BwE

---

Is there any possibility the following options would work?

[image: Possible rear axle alternate for hitch]https://www.thule.com/en-us/accessories/thule-thru-axle-maxle-m12-x-175-_-20100799

[image: Through axle hitch]
[https://www.amazon.com/Thule-Child-Carrier-ezHitch-Release/dp/B00FY2OJTM/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=thule+hitch+carrier&qid=1611192551&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FY2OJTM)

Comment: What is stopping the hitch from being mounted to the Juiced bike?  The image shows an old-school bolt-on rear axle with a separate nut, but some kind of retainer plate.  Is that getting in the way?

Comment: Do you have more than one hitch or are you moving that between bikes?  Would be ideal to have a hitch permanently mounted to each bike to save wear and tear and misalignment issues.